C#. Как в if проверить StreamReader открыт он или нет?
Как в if проверить StreamReader открыт он или нет? Хотел чтобы он возвращал true если объект StreamReader открыт. К сожалению простое Convert.ToBoolean(sr_m) не работает. Помогите пожалуйста.

что значит объект StreamReader открыт?

@Grundy указывает на экземпляр объекта. К примеру: sr_m = File.OpenText(NameFile);

указывает на экземпляр объекта - ты можешь сравнить с null - sr_m == null - если равен - то не указывает на экземпляр объекта. Но, скорее всего, ты хочешь что-то другое. Попробуй добавить больше информации в вопрос, с примерами кода что именно ты делаешь и что хочешь получить

@Grundy Благодарю вас. Всё работает как надо.

Даже если sr_m не равен null, поток, с которым он связан, мог быть закрыт. Например, если вы вызвали метод sr_m.Close() или sr_m.Dispose(), поток закроется, но сам объект StreamReader останется и не будет равен null.
мне кажется стоит добавить еще BaseStream проверку
bool isStreamReaderOpen = sr_m != null && sr_m.BaseStream != null;
if (sr_m != null && sr_m.BaseStream != null && sr_m.BaseStream.CanRead)
{
    // CanRead можете опустить, если вам просто надо проверить открытость
    // StreamReader открыт и поток доступен для чтения
}
else
{
    // StreamReader закрыт или недоступен
}

Попытка выполнить операции чтения с закрытым потоком приведет к исключению ObjectDisposedException
